# Best way to configure a Many-to-Many relation in .NET Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am relatively new to .NET and Entity Framework, and trying to implement a many-to-many relationship using Code First approach.

There seems to be two ways doing this:

**Option 1. EF "recommended" way.**

- [This tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) creates both tables(Student and Course) following convention, and EF will create the join table(StudentCourse) automatically.

**Option 2. Traditional way**

- An Youtube tutorial with this [github repo](https://github.com/etrupja/complete-guide-to-aspnetcore-web-api/tree/main/my-books/Data/Models) creates the tables Book and Author, then the join table Book_Author manually. So we would only update the join table when adding relations.

I am wondering which would be the "recommended" of doing it, especially in terms of maintainability and easiness of querying?

I like the simplicity of option 1, but I also feel like I have more of a "clutch control" with the option 2 as the join table exist as an accessible model.

Not looking for a definite "right" answer, but just hoping for some thoughts and inputs to help me make a decision.

Thank you,

Comment: "I am wondering which would be the "recommended" of doing it, especially in terms of maintainability and easiness of querying?" - that depends entirely on your project, we can't answer that question.

Comment: I use option 2..